Conditional expectation value for geometric distribution
let $X$ be geometrically distributed to parameter $ p \in (0,1)$
I want to compute the conditional expectation:
$\mathbb{E}[X | X > 8 ] := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=k | X > 8)$
My idea:
for
$$\forall k\leq 8 \ : \ \mathbb{P}(X=k | X > 8)=0$$
and since the geometric distribution is memoryless I get $\forall k > 8$:
$$\mathbb{P}(X=k | X > 8)=\mathbb{P}(X=k)=p \cdot (1-p)^{k-1}$$
with this I yield:
$$\sum_{k=9}^{\infty} k \cdot (1-p)^{k-1}p = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+8) \cdot (1-p)^{k+8}p =  (1-p)^8 \cdot(p \cdot E[X] + 9)$$
is this correct?

It is not correct. For $k>8$ we have  $\mathbb{P}(X=k | X > 8)=\mathbb{P}(X=k, X > 8)/P(X>8)=\mathbb{P}(X=k)/P(X>8)$. You forgot to divide by $P(X>8)$.

but since the geometric distribution is memoryless this is $\mathbb{P}(X=k | X >8)=\mathbb{P}(X=k)$ why would I need to use the definition of the conditioned probability? If you calculate this through what you wrote - since the geometric distribution is memoryless - you would end up with $\mathbb{P}(X=k) $ again, wouldn't you?

why do I need to go with the definition of the conditioned probability and cannot use that the geometric distribution is meoryless?

Ah I just used it wrong right? I need to write $\mathbb{P}(X=(k-8)+8 | X > 8)=\mathbb{P}(X=k-8 )$, correct?

so then I end up with $\mathbb{E}[X | X > 8] = \mathbb{E}[X] + 9 $?

Your last sum should be from $k=1$ to $\infty$, not $0$ to $\infty$.

and why is that?
I have
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=k | X >8)= \sum_{k=9}^{\infty} k \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=k-8)=\sum_{k=9}^{\infty} k \cdot p \cdot (1-p)^{k-9}$
then using index shift, splitting the sum into 2 sums, using the definition of $E[X]$ as well as the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p\cdot(1-p)^k = 1$ I end up with $E[X]+9$ .
I think you can follow it, so I have not written it out, so where did I go wrong here?

@Sgt.Slothrop Note: If $\Bbb P_1(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}\mathbf 1_{k\in{1,2,3,\ldots}}$, then $\Bbb E_1(X)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp(1-p)^{k-1}$ and $\Bbb P_1(X>8)=(1-p)^8$:$$\small\begin{align}\Bbb E_1(X\mid X>8)&=\sum_{k=9}^\infty kp(1-p)^{k-1-8}\&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k+8)p(1-p)^{k-1}\&=\Bbb E_1(X+8)\end{align}$$ However: If $\Bbb P_0(X=k)=p(1-p)^k\mathbf 1_{k\in{0,1,2,\ldots}}$, then $\Bbb E_0(X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp(1-p)^k$ and $\Bbb P_0(X>8)=(1-p)^9$:$$\small\begin{align}\Bbb E_0(X\mid X>8)&=\sum_{k=9}^\infty kp(1-p)^{k-9}\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+9)p(1-p)^k\&=\Bbb E_0(X+9)\end{align}$$
